# Intellij Forgetting to recompile before running tests

Tags: intellij-idea-2016

I've recently upgraded to intellij 2016.2.4, and it seems that I can't get my test code to recompile before running a test. I've even triggered rebuilding the entire project, and the tests still run and give the same result even if i change what line the failure should be happening on, or delete the offending test.

I've messed with the "build automatically" tag.  It doesn't seem to do anything. Has anyone experienced this? Any ideas?